# Lower semicontinuous functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the space $A=(C^1([0,1],\mathbb R),\|.\|_{L^\infty})$ norm and look at the functional
$$
\mathcal F: A\to\mathbb R_+, f\mapsto \int_{0}^1\left|f'(t)\right|~\mathrm dt.
$$
This functional is not continuous. My question: Is it lower semi-continuous?
And could there be a meaningful extension of $\mathcal F$ to the closure of $A$ under the $L^\infty$-norm?

Comment: I don't think there is any useful extension of this functional to $L^\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functional is the "length" functional. It is lower-semicontinuous. It can be extended to all continuous function as the usual "length" of a curve. You can extend to all the space $L^\infty$ by letting its value be $+\infty$ on non rectifiable curves.

**Some more details.** 
Consider the functional
$$
\ell(f) = \sup \left\{\sum |f(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i})|\colon 0=x_0\le x_1<x_2<\dots<x_N=1\right\}.
$$
One can prove that if $f\in C^1$ then
$$
\ell(f) = \int |f'(t)|\, dt.
$$

Moreover if $f\in C^0$ then $\ell(f)<+\infty$. The space of $f$ such that $\ell(f)<+\infty$ is called $BV$ (functions of Bounded Variation).

Clearly the functional $\ell$ is lower-semicontinous because it is the $\sup$ of a family of continuous functionals.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a proof of that fact? Thanks.

Comment: How do you extend it? If the curve is continuous then, you can take the sup among the partitions, however, in this bigger space, how do you define the length of a curve?

Comment: @Tomás: The bigger space consists of continuous functions only, so the extension via partitions and polygonal segments makes sense if the value $\infty$ is allowed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made some confusion with the norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and was thinking that the big space were $L^\infty$. I think you should change $L^\infty$ by $C$ in your answer, because I can't see any reasonable way to define the length of a curve in $L^\infty$.

Comment: @Emanuele: Thank you very much - it's clear now! But so there is no direct way to see that (without considering this extension via sup of partitions)? But i guess you mean if $f\in C^0$, then $\ell(f)≤+\infty$...

Comment: Apparently the statement that this functional "clearly it can be extended to every continuous functions" is WRONG. It can not be extended even to all differentiable functions. For example, $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} x^2\sin(1/x) & x\ne 0, \\ 0 & x=o.\end{array}\right.$$ This function is differentiable, but $\int_0^1 |f'|dx=\infty$.

Comment: It would have been lower semi-continuous, as a supremum of continuous, if the supremum was definable!

Answer (score 1):

This functional is DEFINITELY continuous, when defined on $C^1[0,1]$, with its standard norm.

Let $f\in C^1[0,1]$, then
$$
\lvert Af\rvert=\Big\lvert\int_0^1 f'(t)\,dt\Big\rvert\le \int_0^1 \lvert f'\rvert\,dt
\le \int_0^1 \| f'\|_\infty\,dt=\| f'\|_\infty\le \| f\|_\infty+\| f'\|_\infty=\|f\|_{C^1[0,1]}.
$$

Is it lower semi-continuous, w.r.t. to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm?

Let's be reminded of the definition: $A$ is lower semi-continuous at $f=f_0$, if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an open $U\subset C^1[0,1]$ (open w.r.t. to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm), with $f_0\in U$, such that
$$
\int_0^1 \lvert f'(x)\rvert\,dx\le\int_0^1 \lvert f'_0(x)\rvert\,dx+\varepsilon, 
$$
for every $f\in U$.

Apparently this is NOT possible, as if $U$ is open, then $B_\delta(f_0)\subset U$, for some $\delta>0$, and 
$$
f_n=f_0+\frac{\delta}{2}\sin nx\in B_\delta(f_0)\subset U,
$$
and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert Af_n\rvert=\infty.
$$

Comment: Take $f_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$. This converges to 0 in $L^\infty$ but the corresponding sequence $\mathcal F(f_n)$ doesn't. I guess you used the wrong topology or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you need to include the derivative in the norm if you want to make $A$ a Banach space. Otherwise you could approximate crazy functions.

Comment: Yes, but I want to work with the $L^\infty$-norm on purpose. Otherwise the functional becomes continuous anyway (w.r.t. the $C^1$-topology for example).

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: I'm confused about your definition of lower semicontinuity. In my opinion, the rôles of $f$ and $f_0$ seem to be exchanged. And then your example isn't a counterexample.